# Unable to apply JSLink to the field

Tags: 2013, jslink

I want to apply the JSLink file to the field to render it differently.

```
<Field ID="{2F30125C-D2C9-459F-9AC5-1796F52C0C4B}"
     Name="oiplbDepartment"
     StaticName="oiplbDepartment"
     Type="TaxonomyFieldType"
     ShowField="Term1033"
     EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"
     DisplayName="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbDepartmentDisplayName;"
     Description="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,fldoiplbDepartmentDescription;"
     Group="$Resources:OIPLBIntranet,grpFields;"
     DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE"
     JSLink="~siteCollection/Style%20Library/LofbergsIntranet/Scripts/SingleDepartment.js">
```

My jslink file code:

```
(function () {
    var favoriteColorContext = {};

    // You can provide templates for:
    // View, DisplayForm, EditForm and NewForm
    favoriteColorContext.Templates = {};
    favoriteColorContext.Templates.Fields = {
        "oiplbDepartment": {
            "View": favoriteColorViewTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
        favoriteColorContext
        );
})();

// The favoriteColorViewTemplate provides the rendering logic
// the custom field type when it is displayed in the view form.
function favoriteColorViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var color = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    return "<h1>Hello</h1>";
}
```

I am not getting the field rendered differently. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

> Overriding JSLink property via field xml definition or c# code is a
>   nice way to link your JavaScript file to the particular field.
>   However, not all the fields could be overwritten this way.
>
> For example, Taxonomy field has the following JSLink definition:
>
> // Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField public override string

```
 JSLink {
     get
     {
         return "SP.UI.Taxonomy.js|SP.UI.Rte.js(d)|SP.Taxonomy.js(d)|ScriptForWebTaggingUI.js(d)";
     } }
```

> This means you cannot modify the look and feel for your Taxonomy
>   field. Also, you can’t do that for Taxonomy, Related Items or Task
>   Outcome field. All of these fields return particular JSLink which
>   can’t be changed

Please see below for reference

http://spdevlab.com/2013/07/07/5-facts-about-jslink-in-sharepoint-2013-you-might-not-know/

Comment: Nadeem, I think I'm missing something here. Why does the definition (or syntax) preclude modifying the look and feel of a TaxonomyField?